# Powershell script for AzCopy with settings file

Tags: powershell, azure, scripting

I want to automate download from an Azure VM to my local machine using AzCopy. Manually, I did not get any issue whatsoever. I even succeeded to do an automic script to do that. However, now my script doesn't work and used to work... Maybe I missed something or maybe I got lucky.

So here's what I have: 
settings.txt that contains 3 settings, such as the output folder, source (azure storage url) and the sourcekey from Azure storage.
myscript.ps1 that basically get the content from the settings.txt and start AzCopy

My issue is on the sourcekey from Azure, if the key is not directly in myscript.ps1, it doesn't work and I get an error.

My script that works:

```
    Get-Content "C:\ProgramData\NAME\SOFTWARE\Azure\settings\settings.txt" | foreach-object -begin {$h=@{}} -process { $k = [regex]::split($_,'='); if(($k[0].CompareTo("") -ne 0) -and ($k[0].StartsWith("[") -ne $True)) { $h.Add($k[0], $k[1]) } }

$filename="LOG_" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".log"
$log_path="C:\ProgramData\NAME\SOFTWARE\Azure\logs"
$Source=$h.Source
$Key="BLABLABLAMYWEIRDKEY"
$output_path = $h.Output

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy"

.\AzCopy.exe /Source:$Source /Dest:$output_path /SourceKey:$Key /Y /S /V /XO /XN >$log_path\$filename
```

This one works with this settings.txt:

```
[SETTINGS]
Output="C:\Output\DATA\"
Source="https://blablabla.file.core.windows.net/blabla/"
Key="BLABLABLAMYWEIRDKEY"
```

So I tried to do that:

```
    Get-Content "C:\ProgramData\NAME\SOFTWARE\Azure\settings\settings.txt" | foreach-object -begin {$h=@{}} -process { $k = [regex]::split($_,'='); if(($k[0].CompareTo("") -ne 0) -and ($k[0].StartsWith("[") -ne $True)) { $h.Add($k[0], $k[1]) } }

$filename="LOG_" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss") + ".log"
$log_path="C:\ProgramData\NAME\SOFTWARE\Azure\logs"
$Source=$h.Source
$Key=$h.Key
$output_path = $h.Output

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy"

.\AzCopy.exe /Source:$Source /Dest:$output_path /SourceKey:$Key /Y /S /V /XO /XN >$log_path\$filename
```

but i got this error:

```
.\AzCopy.exe : [2018/06/08 17:10:09][ERROR] The syntax of the command is incorrect. The supplied storage key (SourceKey) is not a valid Base64 string.
At F:\Desktop\Azure_DL.ps1:29 char:1
+ .\AzCopy.exe /Source:$Source /Dest:$output_path /SourceKey:$Key /Y /S ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ([2018/06/08 17:... Base64 string.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Any idea ? I really need to have the key information store in a txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some deep search here, I've change the way to call my settings file:

```
   $configFile = "c:\Path2Config"
    if(Test-Path $configFile) {
        Try {
            #Load config appsettings
            $global:appSettings = @{}
            $config = [xml](get-content $configFile)
            foreach ($addNode in $config.configuration.appsettings.add) {
                if ($addNode.Value.Contains(‘,’)) {
                    # Array case
                    $value = $addNode.Value.Split(‘,’)
                        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $value.length; $i++) { 
                            $value[$i] = $value[$i].Trim() 
                        }
                }
                else {
                    # Scalar case
                    $value = $addNode.Value
                }
            $global:appSettings[$addNode.Key] = $value
            }
        }
        Catch [system.exception]{
        }
    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13698982/7470828

Thanks

Comment: Nice downvote when I'm giving the solution. Great community ++